# How to highlight previous links when user moves to the next link?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have 3 components that load in the main App.js compoenet using react routes, like so:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './App.css';
import welcome from './components/welcome/welcome';
import Generalinfo from './components/generalinfo/generalinfo';
import Preferences from './components/preferences/preferences';
import Navigation from './UI/navigation/navigation';
import { Route , BrowserRouter } from 'react-router-dom';


class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <BrowserRouter>
        <div className="App">
          <Navigation />
          <Route path="/" exact component={ welcome } />  
          <Route path="/generalinfo" exact component={ Generalinfo } />
          <Route path="/preferences" exact component={ Preferences } />
        </div>
      </BrowserRouter>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

As you can see the following 3 components are loaded , depending on the url you hit in the browser:

```
  <Route path="/" exact component={ welcome } />  
  <Route path="/generalinfo" exact component={ Generalinfo } />
  <Route path="/preferences" exact component={ Preferences } />
```

I Have a navigation that looks like below:

[image]

The navigation code is below:

```
import React from 'react';
import classes from './navigation.css';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';

const navigation = (props) => {

    const ACTIVE = { background: '#286090', color: '#fff'}

    return (
        <nav className={ classes.main__site__navigation }>
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <Link to="/">
                        1
                    </Link>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <Link to={{
                            pathname : '/generalinfo'
                        }}
                        className={ classes.active }
                    >
                        2
                    </Link>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <Link to={{
                            pathname : '/preferences'
                        }}>
                        3
                    </Link>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    );
}

export default navigation;
```

Now what i would like to do is , say the user is on the 3rd component and final component, So say the user is on the following route:

```
<Route path="/preferences" exact component={ Preferences } />
```

I would like the navigation to highlight the previous 2 links , (to indicate to the user that the previous 2 routes have already been visited, basically these 3 components are survey forms , so the user can't move to the next survey form unless he fills out the previous one's , something like what you see in shopping sites on the checkout page.) How do i accomplish this though , i know i can have the active class added to the current link , but how do i track and highlight the previous links when the user moves to the next link ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you can do to match the previous active link is to store the matches, to achieve that you can convert the Navigation component to a stateful component and store the visited links in state

```
class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <BrowserRouter>
        <div className="App">
          <Navigation />
          <Route path="/" exact component={ welcome } />  
          <Route path="/generalinfo" exact component={ Generalinfo } />
          <Route path="/preferences" exact component={ Preferences } />
        </div>
      </BrowserRouter>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Navigation:

```
class Navigation extends React.Component {
    state = {
        activeLink: []
    }
    handleClick = (path) => {
        if(!this.state.activeLink.includes(path)) {
           this.setState(prevState => ({ activeLink: [...prevState.prevState, path ] }))
        }
    }
    render(){
        const ACTIVE = { background: '#286090', color: '#fff'}
        const { activeLink } = this.state;
        return (
            <nav className={ classes.main__site__navigation }>
                <ul>
                    <li>
                        <Link to="/"  onClick={() => this.handleClick('/')} className={ activeLink.includes("/") ? classes.active: '' } >
                            1
                        </Link>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <Link to={{
                                pathname : '/generalinfo'
                            }}
                            className={ activeLink.includes("/generalinfo") ? classes.active: '' }
                            onClick={() => this.handleClick('/generalinfo')}
                        >
                            2
                        </Link>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <Link to={{
                                pathname : '/preferences'
                            }}
                            onClick={() => this.handleClick('/preferences')} 
                            className={ activeLink.includes("/preferences") ? classes.active: '' }
                    >
                            3
                        </Link>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
        );
    }

}

export default Navigation;
```

Comment: `const { activeLink } = this.state;` is this ES6 ? does't quite get what this does ..

Comment: @AlexanderSolonik, Its a destructuring syntax, you can check more about it here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment

Answer (score 1):

You can have conditional active classes if you use `<NavLink>` and utilize the `isActive` prop to determine when a certain `<NavLink>` should be shown as active.

In this case, you could just have a function that checks if the current url matches any of the previous ones to determine

```
// only consider a link active if its equal to or less than a certain url
const matchEvent = (match, location) => {
if (!match) {
    return false
}
const links = ["/", "/generalinfo", "/preferences"]
   return location.pathname <= links.indexOf(location.pathname)
}

<NavLink
  to="/generalinfo"
  isActive={matchEvent}
>General Info</NavLink>
```

The above is just an example of one way you could accomplish it, but you should certainly do something that would be a little more extensible than that.

Comment: Thanks , will look into this , please give me sometime

Answer (score 0):

I think you could use the classnames package and set the class for visited links to true in an onClick event handler. That would not persist across reloads though. If you wanted that you would need to save the setting to local storage or something.

Comment: what is the point of using react if you have to use localStorage ?